# Renaming a column starting with '?column?'

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I want to rename the column in Postgresql database. The column name i am having is :

```
id varchar
?column?    text
name varchar
```

I have tried using the following command:

```
alter table <table_name> rename column '?column?' to age;
```

But i am getting error. Please help me in renaming the column without dropping or recreating the table.

Comment: "but I am getting error". What error? show the **exact text of the error message** in questions about errors, as well as your PostgreSQL version. In this case we can guess what's going on pretty easily, but that won't always be the case and you'll get a better response from people if you provide all the details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use double quotes for identifiers:

```
alter table <table_name> rename column "?column?" to age;
```

Comment: Heh, within a second of each other. Removing my answer.